# SQL - Mixing inner join with a left join

Tags: sql

I have a SQL Server database with three tables: Gang,  GangMember, and Neighborhood. These tables are structured like this:

```
Neighborhood
------------
ID (non-null)
Name (non-null)

Gang
----
ID (non-null)
Name (non-null)
NeighborhoodID (nullable)

GangMember
----------
ID (non-null)
GangID (non-null)
Name (non-null),
Position (nullable)
```

I need to get all gangs a gang member belongs to (yes they can belong to multiple). If there is a neighborhood, I need to return that as well. I want my result set to be in the form of: gang.name, neighborhood.name, member.position

So far, I've gotten here:

```
SELECT
 g.[Name],
 '' as 'Neighborhood' /* This what I don't know how to do */
 m.[Position]
FROM
  [Gang] g, 
  [GangMember] m
WHERE
  m.[GangID]=g.[ID]
```

Because a gang may not have a neighborhood, I'm not sure how to complete this query. Can somebody help me out? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have some update anomalies and other problems in your model.  I don;t think you have properly defined what a gang member is e.g. "gang member belongs to (yes they can belong to multiple)" seems to be contradictory. Perhaps you mean that the same *person* can be a member of the same gang? If so, presumably they could be known by different names (or the same name) in different gangs for their own protection. Knowing the tradition of rivalry between gangs and their anti-establishment nature, it's hard for me to imagine which agency would be the trusted source of a gang member ID!

Comment: To clarify: I think your `GangMember` table needs to be split out into two tables: one to model the person (which may have identifiers such as legal name, finger prints, DNA, etc) and another to model the relationship between the person and her gangs (hard for me to imagine any identifier other than 'known as' name).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  g.[Name],
  n.[Name] as 'Neighborhood',
  m.[Position]
FROM 
  [Gang] g INNER JOIN [GangMember] m ON m.[GangID]=g.[ID]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Neighborhood] n ON g.[NeighborhoodID] = n.[ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select G.Name as GangName,
       N.Name as Neighborhood,
       GM.Name as MemberName,
       GM.Position as MemberPosition
from Gang as G
  inner join GangMember as GM
    on G.ID = GM.GangID
  left outer join Neighborhood as N
    on G.NeighborhoodID = N.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the left join as follows:

```
SELECT 
 g.[Name], 
 n.name as 'Neighborhood' /* This what I don't know how to do */ 
 m.[Position] 
FROM 
  [Gang] g 
  INNER JOIN [GangMember] m ON m.[GangID]=g.[ID]
  LEFT JOIN Neighborhood n ON n.Id = g.NeighborhoodID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    DemographicTable.Name,
    ReferralTable.Code,
    ReferralTable.Date_Termed,
    ReferralTable.Referral_date,
    (
        SELECT Date_Accepted
        FROM CaseTable
        WHERE (ReferralTable.ID = DemographicTable.ID_Number)
            AND (Date_Accepted <> '')
            AND (DateTermed > '2013-11-01' OR DateTermed = '')
    ) AS Start,
    (
        SELECT DateTermed
        FROM CaseTable AS CaseTable_1
        WHERE (ReferralTable.ID = DemographicTable.ID_Number)
            AND (Date_Accepted <> '')
            AND (DateTermed > '2013-11-01' OR DateTermed = '')
    ) AS Term
FROM ReferralTable
INNER JOIN DemographicTable
    ON ReferralTable.ID = DemographicTable.ID_Number
    AND ReferralTable. Referral_date > '2012-12-01'
    AND ReferralTable. Code = 'JTC'
ORDER BY ReferralTable. Referral_date
```